# Inline styles in RSS feed?

Tags: rss, inline-styles

Is it ok to have inline styles in an RSS feed?

Im making an RSS feed for a site which uses content that itself has been imported and contains inline styles. Will these be used or ignored by readers, and could they cause any other issues?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSS feed isn't really meant to be styled in any way, readers style them for themselves. They can contain HTML tags in places like titles or descriptions, however adding tags in other places might cause some issues.

See [the W3 rss feed tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/rss/default.asp)

Comment: Note that that's a link to w3schools, which has no affiliation with the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/). See also http://w3fools.com/ for some opinions on w3schools from a fair few well-know web developers.

Comment: Edited, thanks. My reference here was the overall structure of the said RSS feed, I've taken first RSS feed example I've found in a quick search.